# Fast evaluation of function along all index combinations of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

Let `A,B` be `((a1,a2,a3))` numpy arrays and `f` a function taking two `((a3))` arrays as arguments and returning a float. I want to create a new `((a1,a2,a2))` numpy array as follows

```
C[i,j,k]=f(A[i,j,:],B[i,k,:])
```

In other words, I want to apply `f` to all combinations of indices over the second axis `a2`. Is there a faster way than just looping over all combinations (e.g. vectorizing f or something along these lines)? Ideally it should generalize to the same situation with more axes (that is, `A,B` are `((a1,...,an))` numpy arrays and we return a numpy array with `n` axes that is of shape `((a1,...,a_(n-2),a_(n-1),a_(n-1))`).

Edit: A typical example of the function `f` would be `numpy.exp(const*np.inner(a-b,a-b))` where `a,b`  are `(a3))` numpy arrays.

Comment: Could you give a small example for A, B and the expected output?

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but you'll need to tell us what the actual function is

Comment: Thanks - I now added an example.

Comment: Create a `meshgrid` over your axis a2 from A and B. Alternatively, one can call a function over a grid as `numpy.fromfunction`.